# What's the translation of pricing oneself out of something in French?

Tags: traduction, finance

[Example of use](https://www.mirror.co.uk/sport/other-sports/mma/conor-mcgregor-ufc-fight-news-31999966):

> Conor McGregor has been accused of **pricing himself out** in his UFC comeback fight against Michael Chandler.

What's the translation of pricing oneself out of something in French? [Google Translate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBKgn.png) and Linguee weren't helpful.

This is in the sense of asking for a price that is so unreasonably high that it'll get rejected.

Comment: As an English/American speaker this is not a familiar expression to me either. This is difficult to translate because in the text itself the term in question is actually defined in-article: "... It’s called pricing yourself out of the market. With Conor, it doesn’t matter if the excuse is the weight class ..." - What is the context of the translation? How you translate something like this will depend on what the translation is for, e.g. if it's for explanation purposes, maybe a literal translation would be appropriate (and to inform the reader that it is such).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it means here? I understand the meaning for a product (raising the price too much, so that no one buys the thing anymore), but not for a UFC fighter...

Comment: @TeleportingGoat Asking for a price that is so unreasonably high that it'll get rejected. I have read that term several times.

Comment: @Brandin thanks, it's not for explanation purpose, just trying to convey the meaning.

Comment: "Conor McGregor a été accusé de s'être déclaré un prix exorbitant pour s'auto-exclure du marché" ?

Comment: Did you try overpricing?

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest something like *... accusé de se défiler de son match / d'esquiver son match en demandant un prix excessif* (literally, accused of chickening out / of dodging by asking for too much).

Or, with a different nuance: *accusé de se mettre hors jeu / hors compétition à l'avance de son match par ses demandes financières excessives*.

As a rule of thumb, these *verb + preposition* constructions get reversed in French: the meaning conveyed by the preposition in English becomes the verb in French, and the English verb becomes a gerund or some sort of adverbial clause. A classic example is *traverser en courant* for *run across the street*.

In the process one must draw from context to make the French verb more specific than the preposition could be. Sometimes this is a bit of an editorial decision, and here the context is actually insufficient to know if the accusation is one of cowardice or of greed / snobbery.

Comment: j'aime bien, mais dans ma compréhension, "se défiler/s'esquiver" porte une aspect péjoratif qui n'est pas présent dans l'expression anglaise (plus connoté marché/économie).

Comment: @XouDou tout à fait, c'est donc justifié si cet aspect péjoratif est confirmé par le contexte élargi, ça ne l'est pas sinon. J'ai rajouté une alternative.

Answer (score 3):

[Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/anglais-francais/price/603966#603970) en ligne anglais-français donne pour « price out » avec un élément réfléchi des trucs comme « perdre... à cause de ses prix trop élevés » ou « il n'a pas été embauché parce qu'il a demandé un salaire trop élevé », similaire à [une autre réponse](https://french.stackexchange.com/a/54184/26366).

Je propose dans la même veine :

> On a accusé Conor de s'être rendu hors de prix pour son retour au
> combat dans la UFC l'opposant à Chandler.

Answer (score 3):

One thing that the English sentence conveys well through the phrasal verb but needs more emphasis in French is intentionality. I find it more idiomatic to add "sciemment" or "exprès" for a fraudulent connotation.

To keep the reflexivity, I would translate "to price oneself" as *s'afficher (à un prix)*, which also emphasizes the "appearance vs reality" aspect.

> On a accusé Conor McGregor de s'être sciemment affiché à un prix trop élevé pour (éviter) son match de grand retour contre Michael Chandler.

Answer (score 1):

> Conor McGregor a été accusé de s'être déclaré un prix exorbitant pour
> s'auto-exclure du marché. (Stef, en [commentaire](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/54177/whats-the-translation-of-pricing-oneself-out-of-something-in-french#comment115497_54177))